# Setup SunFire 440 Raid Configuration

Tags: raid, freebsd, solaris, raid5, sun

How can I setup Internal Hard disk RAID5 configuration?
I have SunFire 440 machine with 4 internal hard disk. I have never worked on Sun systems except for now and I am exploring google for the above solution. If anyone could help me out.

Comment: Did you had a look into this [Administration Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19088-01/v440.srvr/816-7728-10/816-7728-10.pdf)?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-4520/tasks-raid5-6.html

Answer (score 0):

Software:

- Solaris 10: use SVM `metainit` command as linked in the comments already
- Solaris 11: use ZFS (raidZ), see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54801/gcvjg.html#scrolltoc

Hardware:

- RAID 5 not supported by the controller on the V440. Mirroring is supported though. Use the `raidctl` command, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19088-01/v440.srvr/816-7728-10/816-7728-10.pdf

Comment: to use raidctl and metainit, do we need installed solaris os to run the command??

Comment: Yes, those are Solaris commands.