# #raidctl - Operation not support with volume of this level

Tags: raid, freebsd, solaris, lsi, sun

I am having problem to create a RAID volume on the internal disks of a Sun Server (Sunf Fire V440)

When I type the below command
`raidctl -f -c -r 5 c1t0d0 c1t1d0 c1t2d0 c1t3d0`

 it displays
`Operation not support with volume of this level.`

My controller is "LSI_1030"

 Help me out please

Comment: The answer here is the same as the answer to your other question. Please spend spend some time reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It has already been said in [Setup SunFire 440 Raid Configuration](https://serverfault.com/questions/750113/setup-sunfire-440-raid-configuration) that the onboard controller only supports mirroring, no raid 5.

As per http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19088-01/v440.srvr/816-7728-10/816-7728-10.pdf :

*On the Sun Fire V440 server, the Ultra-4 SCSI controller supports internal hardware disk mirroring using the Solaris operating environment raidctl utility*